# Display ACF Taxonomy in order of Multi Select order

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

Using ACF, I have a Taxonomy field with Multi Select and Stylized UI.

I usually have 2 or 3 tax items selected.

I can arrange them using drag and drop. It's wonderful.

**On the front end, the array does not reflect the tax order/sorting that I put in place.**

Pretty easy code. What am I doing wrong?

```
                        <?php

                        $values = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'languages' );

                        if ( $values ) {
                            echo '<tr class="item"><td>';

                                        foreach ( $values as $value ) {
                                            echo $value->name . '<br/>';
                                        }

                            echo '</td></tr>';
                        }
                        ?>
```

Comment: It looks like your only getting the terms, but not querying the sort order. I can't tell where you're storing the sort order exactly from what you've posted. If it's in ACF, you may need to query the ACF field, otherwise try adding the orderby and order arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I’ll circle back on Monday and query the ACF field differently. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Figured it out.**
Because the field saved the correct sorting in the admin field, I knew the order data was saved somewhere. I looked in the database at the post's terms and the associated data. The order was saved there. Instead of using get_the_terms for the loop, I used get_post_meta. That gave me an array with the term IDs in the correct order. Then I got the term name using that ID within a foreach loop. This gave me the taxonomy names in the order from the styled multi-select field.

```
                        <?php

                        $values = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'languages' );
                        if ( $values ) {
                            echo '<tr class="item"><td>';

                            $values = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'languages' );

                            foreach ( $values as $value ) {
                                foreach ( $value as $item ) {
                                    $term = get_term( $item )->name; 
                                    echo $term .'<br/>';    
                                }
                            }

                            echo '</td></tr>';

                        }
                        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old thread but for those looking for the ACF-version:

```
<?php $terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => '[YOUR TAXONOMY HERE]',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'include' => $ids,
    'orderby' => 'include', // Order by your include
) );
//Rest of your code
?>
```